# How to work with youtube api V3

Tags: api, youtube, get

I need help with youtube API V3.
as when on the browser I type:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=Titanic%201997%20Official%20Trailer&key=
it's show return values.
However I am trying to collect the array from php.

How can I use GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=Titanic%201997%20Official%20Trailer&key= in php so I get the result in php?

or is there any option to get the search result in a rss feed format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple video search on YouTube API and you will get video title, description, video id and image source so best approach full code is given below.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$search = "Search Query"; // Search Query

$api = "YouTube API Key"; // YouTube Developer API Key

$results = 10; // Max results

$link = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=moderate&order=relevance&part=snippet&q=".urlencode($search). "&maxResults=$results&key=". $api;

$video = file_get_contents($link);

$video = json_decode($video, true);

foreach ($video['items'] as $data){
        $title = $data['snippet']['title'];
        $description = $data['snippet']['title'];
        $vid = $data['id']['videoId'];
        $image = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$vid/default.jpg";

        // Output Title/Description/Image URL If Video ID exist
        if($vid){
            echo "Title: $title<br />Description: $description<br />Video ID: $vid<br />Image URL: $image<hr>";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: for searching videos (relevance) use this url you can get videoId and title , image url etc. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&contentdetails&q=SEARCH KEY&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&key=YOUR API KEY&maxResults=25

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&contentdetails&q={SERCH KEY}&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&key={YOUR API KEY}&maxResults=25

Comment: How do you format the url to submit multiple **parts** parameters as this is not working for me?